# Function for Validate Email

Tags: javascript

I tried to create a function for Validate Email in three cases:

1. check the email text field whether it contains ‘@’ for any email address.
2. make sure that the email field is not empty
   3)it does not contain more than 100 characters.

my problem is that when I press submit, it just checks for ‘@’ even when the field is empty [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Zzv2.png)

this is my code from Apache NetBean:

for form:

```
<form method="post" action ="" novalidate onsubmit="return ValidateRadioButtons(), ValidateEmail()">
```

for email:

```
            <input type = "text" name ="email" id = "email" placeholder="aaa@ucj.edu.sa" onchange="ValidateEmail()" >
```

for function:

```
    function ValidateEmail() {
        var email = document.getElementById("email");
        if (email.value.length > 100) {
            window.alert("Email address should not contain more 100 than characters");
            email.focus();
            return false;
        } else if (email.value.indexOf("@") < 0) {
            window.alert("Email address should  contain @ character");
            email.focus();
            return false;
        } else if (email.value.length === 0) {
            window.alert("You should enter Email address");
            email.focus();
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You check for "@" before you check for empty field.

Comment: @gre_gor: I thought there is a big mistake, but it works... thank you so much!

Comment: Yeah and also just so you know, it enters the else if condition where you check the index of @, because the indexOf() method returns -1 (<0) if the provided char is not present, and it is certainly not present in empty string :D

Comment: While you're at it: if you're `if` statement include a `return` no need for `else if` you can just use `if`. `return` will prevent the else part of the if from happening.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I validate an email address in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-can-i-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if the length is 0 first, then the maximum length. Then you can check the required @  if the previous checks are ok!

```
function ValidateEmail() {
    var email = document.getElementById("email");
    if (email.value.length ===0 ) {
        window.alert("You should enter Email address");
        email.focus();
        return false;
    } else if (email.value.length > 100) {
        window.alert("Email address should not contain more 100 than characters");
        email.focus();
        return false;
    } else if (email.value.indexOf("@") < 0) {
        window.alert("Email address should  contain @ character");
        email.focus();
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```